# Node.js multithread program

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, web-worker, worker

I wrote a node.js script to fetch some prices from exchanges. It looks like this:

```
async function main() {
  async function func() {
    var start_time = performance.now();
    for (let route of routes) {
      var result_amount = await calc(route, amount_wei);
          if (result_amount[5] > amount_start * 1) {
              console.log("Good Trade");
    }
  while (true) {
     await func();
  }
}
```

and one route (route of routes) looks like this:

```
[
    "quick / sushi - 1x1",
    token_Address_usdc,
    token_Address_dai,
    token_Address_usdc,
    "-",
    "-",
    "USDC - DAI - USDC",
  ]
```

So first I am fetching the output if I swap usdc to dai on quickswap. Then from dai to usdc on sushiswap. I save the output in an array (`result_amount`) and give it back to the main program (Now result is compared to the start amount).

I do have like 10 trading routes and the program needs about 20 seconds, so 2 seconds per route.
The routes are absolutely independent from each other, so it should be possible to fetch all routes at the same time right?
I have read something about multi threads with `workers`, but I have to say, I didn't get it. Can someone help me with this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Stop using await and use `Promise.all`

This will allow you to wait for all of your data to come in in parallel, rather than serially

```
function func() {
  var promises = [];
  for (let route of routes) {
    promises.push (calc(route, amount_wei));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(completedItems) {
    completedItems.forEach(function(val) {
      var result_amount = val;
      if (result_amount[5] > amount_start * 1) {
        console.log("Good Trade");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can ditch the `async` keyword here, since you don't use `await` anywhere in the function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this out, but now I get the error: `FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`. How can I handle this one?

Comment: @DaniS Out of memory errors are common across all programming languages. If you search the web for this error (I just tried this myself) you will find a lot of useful information

Comment: I tried to optimize the heap space using `node --max-old-space-size=8192 --optimize-for-size index.js` But this one is running very long (Much longer than the 20 seconds by fetching prices sequentially.
And I am thinking if there is a solution to set heap space out of my index.js file, so I do not have to insert this every time I run the script?

Comment: this code won't even parse

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that node.js is generally single threaded and not multithreaded. Even though asynchronous operations sometime give the impression of parallelism, it is not a requirement. Meaning, just because an operation is asynchronous, does not mean it has to run in its separate thread.

> The routes are absolutely independent from each other, so it should be possible to fetch all routes at the same time right?

It depends, the easiest case would be complete independence, where the result of said request isn't used in conjunction with the results of other fetches.

You really didn't provide too much detail, so it's not really possible to answer your question.

What I can recommend, though, is: always try to avoid multithreading if possible.

[ControlAltDel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73901217/2005038)'s answer is a good starting point.

Comment: I have added a few informations. How can I make the requests independent?