# Node.js Promise.all - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fatal-error

I tried to fetch some data in node.js in parallel, so the program is faster compared to fetching them sequentially.
I do it like that:

```
function func() {
  var promises = [];
  for (let route of routes) {
    promises.push (calc(route, amount_wei));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(completedItems) {
    completedItems.forEach(function(val) {
      var result_amount = val;
      if (result_amount[5] > amount_start * 1) {
        console.log("Good Trade");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I got help for this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901023/node-js-multithread-program).

I do have like 10 routes, so the for loop should run 10 iterations.
But no matter what I try, I got an error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[23272:000001FDFC5C4DE0]   126463 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 9852.7 (10047.2) -> 9852.3 (10047.9) MB, 9776.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.350, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[23272:000001FDFC5C4DE0]   136795 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 9853.4 (10047.9) -> 9853.0 (10048.7) MB, 10314.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.201, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6487D7C4F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114207
 2: 00007FF648765EC6 DSA_meth_get_flags+65542
 3: 00007FF648766D7D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF64909B6CE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF649085CAD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF648F2907C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF648F26194 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+4244
 8: 00007FF648F23B10 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+2000
 9: 00007FF648F48696 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+214
10: 00007FF648C7AB65 v8::internal::DateCache::Weekday+1797
11: 00007FF6491293C1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
12: 00007FF6490EB013 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+239523
13: 000001FD8014DF37
```

I read nearly every page corresponding to this error but cannot solve it.
I tried to set an environmental variable `NODE_OPTIONS` to `--max-old-space-size=8192`.
I tried to run the program with the command: `node --max-old-space-size=8192 index.js`

If it helps, I got my heapStatistics here:

```
{
  total_heap_size: 55885824,
  total_heap_size_executable: 786432,
  total_physical_size: 55885824,
  total_available_size: 10505880728,
  used_heap_size: 29100784,
  heap_size_limit: 10536091648,
  malloced_memory: 794688,
  peak_malloced_memory: 4109184,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 1,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: For 10 routes, this code by itself will not cause that error unless `calc()` is either an infinite loop or uses massive amount of memory all by itself so there is apparently more to the relevant code than you are showing here.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your original code in your previous question, the answer there missed one very important detail ...

```
while(true) {
    func();
}
```

Also, the code in the answer won't even parse!!! But you must've figured that out for yourself or you wouldn't have the issue you are having (a missing `)` in that answer)

Now that you are no longer waiting for the `calc` function "inline", that loop will runaway using as much resources until *bang* it dies from lack of memory or whatever

You need to wait for `func` to finish each "round" of `calc`s

So - perhaps something like

```
async function func() {
    const promises = routes.map(route => calc(route, amount_wei));
    const completedItems = await Promise.all(promises);
    completedItems.forEach(function (result_amount) {
        if (result_amount[5] > amount_start * 1) {
            console.log("Good Trade");
        }
    });
}
```

Now, you must

```
while (true) {
    await func();
}
```

Though, there's probably better way to do so, so that each `route` can work independently, re-running `calc` - but that's an exercise for you if you believe you want to do it that way

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer, this one helped a lot and my script works. But what you mean with you last sentence? I am calling each route independet I think, all of them running on their own. What would you do another way?